# Use pipes to change the input entered using cat command in child process in C

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, fork, cat

I have an operating systems problem where I need to execute the 'cat' command in the child process. The child process is created using fork() system call. While running 'cat' command in the terminal, the input entered in the terminal should be read and converted to another string. Example: 'dog' entered in the terminal should be converted to 'fish'. The program should use pipe() system call to read the input and output the converted string.
Example of the output after 'cat' command is executed:

```
dog
fish
dog
fish
```

My current output after 'cat' command is executed:

```
dog
dog
hh
hh
```

I have included my C code but it does not read the input of 'cat' command.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

void main(int argc , char *argv[]){
    int fd[2];
    int fd2[2];
    char fixed_str[] = "forgeeks.org";
    pid_t childpid;

    if (pipe(fd)==-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" );
        return 1;
    }
    if (pipe(fd2)==-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed" );
        return 1;
    }
    childpid = fork();

    printf("before if");
    if (childpid < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "fork Failed" );
        return 1;

    } else if(childpid == 0){
        char input_str[100];

        printf("child");
        /*
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

        char* myargs[] = {"cat",NULL};
        execvp(myargs[0], myargs);
        printf("cat executed");
      //  scanf("%s", input_str);
        read(fd[0], input_str, 100);
        close(fd[0]);
*/
        close(fd2[0]);
        dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, fd2[1]);
        char* myargs[] = {"cat",NULL};
        execvp(myargs[0], myargs);

        /*
        int k = strlen(input_str);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<strlen(fixed_str); i++)
            input_str[k++] = fixed_str[i];

        input_str[k] = '\0';   // string ends with '\0'
        */

        write(fd2[1], input_str, strlen(input_str)+1);
        close(fd2[1]);

    } else {

        printf("parent");
        char concat_str[100];

        close(fd2[1]);
        dup2(STDIN_FILENO, fd2[0]);
        wait(NULL);
        printf("after wait");
        int l = strlen(concat_str);
        int m;
        for (m=0; m<strlen(fixed_str); m++)
            concat_str[l++] = fixed_str[m];

        concat_str[l] = '\0';   // string ends with '\0'
        read(fd2[0], concat_str, strlen(concat_str)+1);
        printf("%s",concat_str);
        close(fd2[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is difficult to follow. Could you rewrite your example in a clearer way (i.e. don't use "cat" for both the command and the input, give a clear example showing us the behavior you want from each process)?

Comment: You should distinguish between "command line" and "terminal".  Much of what you are writing does not actually make any sense.

Comment: strings entered at the command line are available in the `argv` array.  Input written to the terminal will be made available to be read from stdin.

Comment: You've commented out the correct `dup2`s.  The boiler plate is `dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO); close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);` (close the fd after you dup it, and the unused end of the pipe.)